# Maximise value of diamond given a depreciation rate

Tags: finance, mathematical-modeling

The estimated value of a diamond purchased for investment purposes is determined by $S(t)=250(1.75)^{\sqrt[4]{t}}$.
If the rate of depreciation is $7 \%$ under continuous compounding, how much should the diamond be held to maximize its current price?

I dont get how can i apply the 7 percent under continuous compounding to the equation. And also after  apply it how can I find the the present value of the diamond?

Comment: If the value of the diamond decreases 7% continuously the you have to multiply the estimated value by the $e^{-0.07\cdot t}$

Comment: this qn doesnt make sense. estimated value increases with time, so it appreciates, yet it also depreciates. also, how long a diamond is held shouldn't affect its current price, only its profit.